# Is speed of light is the only way to measure time

Tags: special-relativity, speed-of-light, time, time-dilation

After reading up on special relativity, I understood that because of Einstein's postulates

-the speed of light in free space is a universal constant
Everytime we measure time for an event, directly or indirectly we use speed of light to measure time.
For example now if we try to explain time dilation in special relativity.,
We will say this [explanation of time dilation](https://youtu.be/n4XWWhmxsrI)

So is there any other way by which we can measure time of events in special relativity?

Comment: We can measure time quite well using atomic clocks. We defined $c$ to be exactly 299792458m/s, so we can measure distances by timing how long it takes light to traverse them.

Comment: The speed of light is used to measure distance.

Comment: @QuIcKmAtHs why did you fix only *one* of the dozen spelling/grammatical errors in this post?

Comment: @KyleKanos apologies, I only edited that because it was rather glaring.

Comment: @QuIcKmAtHs so the "i", the misplaced & missing commas, "their", etc aren't glaring!?

Comment: @KyleKanos i have edited it.  Should be more understandable now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Everytime we measure time for an event ,directly or indirectly we use speed of light to measure time.

This isn't true. What gave you this idea?

> So isn't their any other way by which we can measure time in events in special relativity or this is the only reason for all the results produced by special relativity

Any process at all can act as a clock in SR. For example, a spring-wound clock works.

Comment: Well i got confused in asking the question so i asked a wrong one